# defining normals on an object

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I have a quad in which I rotate after within my renderscene method by 90 degrees so the front face of the quad will be facing upwards.  I was wondering if I wanted to set normals should I set the normals before it has rotated or after it has rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend on what datenwolf has said:Normals are defined in local space.Together with the vertices.If your quad front is up ,then you will have to define for each vertex a normal to be

```
  normal=  {0 , 1 , 0 }
```

Then in the vertex shader you transform it by a normal matrix.

Comment: Hi Michael I was a bit confused because my quad was facing towards the screen first until I rotated the model and multiplied it to the view matrix.  So wasn't sure whether to set the normals to 0,0,1 or 0,1,0

Comment: It really depends on the default facing of the front .In my engine for instance the default quad facing is towards the screen (front) so I define my normals {0,0,1}

Comment: say if I defined my normal to be 0,0,1 and then rotated it by 90 degrees would the normals still be at 0,0,1?

Comment: They will be 0,0,1 in the local space no matter what you do with the model.You don't rotate the normal.You rotate the model matrix.The problem start with non uniform scaling.THat is why you should transform normals with normal matrix

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you process normals in the shaders. If you take the normal transformation to be the transpose inverse of the modelview (the usual) then normals are in model local space.